Drupal multistage webform ECK entity reference token
I have a multi-stage webform where a user will select courses they wish to enrol a user too and on the last page it will confirm the products. This is being done as a checkbox populated by an entity reference view.
On the last page I am trying to print out the options selected but the only thing I can get to work will only print the first option and not the others selected.
[webform_submission:values:available_courses:entity:field_product_title]
Any ideas on what I can use in the tokens to display all the products that the person has selected in the available_courses field and not just the first one?

You could post the YAML of a small form for an accurate answer.
